# How to refresh file view

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

In Enterprise Guide 4.2, is there a way to refresh your view of a file short of deleting it from the Process Flow then reopening it?

My Google-fu has failed to provide an answer (one way or the other) and my SAS admin has said he's not aware of a way (but to let him know if I find one).

A definitive "no" (from documentation) or a "yes" with example would be much appreciated.

---

I have a log file that's updated when I run my SAS program from the command line (outside of EG). I edit my code within EG, and I'd like to peek at the log file to see the results. Currently I have to delete the log file from my Process Flow then reopen it to see the updated log.

Comment: Do you mean a SAS file, or a non-SAS file?

Comment: I wouldn't think it'd matter, but it's a non-sas file (a log, actually).

Comment: I am confused by your word choice (perhaps because I am primarily a Base SAS person).  When you say 'your view of a file', what are you referring to specifically; and what are you referring to when you say 'refresh' - is this something that is on the server and is running independently of your EG session, and you want to periodically peek at?

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm using EG as a development environment, but I'm programming in Base SAS.

Comment: Interesting.  You're using EG like a lot of people use UltraEdit (also capable of running SAS batch files, and doing pretty good SAS syntax highlighting).  Curious, why not just right-click to run the step in EG and then look at the log that comes back from that?

Comment: Is this the equivalent of 1) right click on PF, open file -> other; select "c:\temp\test.txt"; opens and adds to PF.  2) Make some change to c:\temp\test.txt.  3) View c:\temp\test.txt and see updated results?

Comment: I'm running the program from a command line (Putty) and then viewing the log using EG ("'cause that's what I got") by double clicking the .LOG file from the Server List. I make a correction, then rerun from the console. Now I want to see the updated .LOG file, but I have to delete the file from the process flow then reopen it to see updates.

Answer (score 1):

From your last comment on your question, it sounds like you are running a non-interactive SAS program on a server (from a PuTTY session) and looking at the log file with your EG client, is that correct?  If so, there are much easier ways to watch the log file.

When you mention PuTTY, I'll assume your server is UNIX.  If so, use the `tail` command with the `-f` option.  For example, if your SAS program is named "myprog.sas", it will create a log file named "myprog.log", so try this command at your UNIX prompt:

```
tail -f myprog.log
```

The `-f` option means to continue writing output to your terminal window as lines are written to the log.  When you get tired of watching (or your see the SAS "end of job" message), type the letter "q" to quit.

EG in intended to be the application that you use to actually execute your SAS program.  Running things from the UNIX prompt is outside the design (and you lose all those cool EG features), as well as miss out any site features that have been set up for you in the metadata environment.

If I'm completely off-base, please clarify your question.

Comment: No, your not off base. I use EG for development, but the sas programs are eventually migrated to a scheduled batch environment. During the migration to "production", I run the program from the command line to simulate the scheduler. EG remains the easiest way to view the log, except it's inconvenient to view the latest updates. Unfortunately, the logs are many hundreds of lines long, so tail wouldn't be very effective.

Comment: Have you ever used tool called WinSCP?  With that, you can open the log file from your server and "refresh" it periodically.  That's in fact what I do with my production jobs (logs are stored in application directories in which I have read access).

Comment: My company is pretty restrictive when it comes to tools. I have EG, and then any command line editors (like vi). I know EG wasn't designed for what I'm trying to use it for, but that's all I've got for now.

Comment: PuTTY is in the same class as WinSCP; both are widely used PC software.  You might find others in your company are always using it. Not an endorsement, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When using SAS EG or SAS Studio in a SAS platform were the compute nodes are hosted in Linux machines, I always use code to see the contents of an output file created by SAS; The only requirements are that you know the fullpath of the file you want to browse and that you have the privileges to read from it.

The simple idea is to use a generic DATA step to:

1. Access the file
2. Read line by line
3. Filter the data, by contents, position, line number, etc.
4. Print the data to the SAS log so you can see it there

Here is a simple example to get you going:

- First I create a file for the test. You already have it!, so use yours.

  ```
  /* create a test file */
  data _null_;
    file '/folders/myshortcuts/test/file'; /* Note I'm using fullpath */
    put "The begining, :)";
    put "line 2 in my file is shy and likes to hide.";
    put "line 3, all good so far.";
    put "line 4 in my file is to remain private.";
    put "Finally the last line in my file!";
  run;
  ```
- Then, here is the code to read its data

  ```
  data _null_;
    /*--------
      references which input file will be read
      setting variable 'theEnd'=1 when 
      reaches end-of-file 
      Note I'm using fullpath
      --------*/
    infile '/folders/myshortcuts/test/file' end=theEnd;

    /*--------
       reads one line at a time from input file 
       storing it in variable _infile_
      --------*/
    input;

    /*--------
      contents of file will be writen in the log, to keep it readable,
      mark where the contents of the file will follow
      --------*/
    if _n_=1 then
      put "-----start file ----";

    /*--------
      filter out shy, private or unwanted data
      --------*/
    if _n_ ne 4;  /* continue only if row number is not 4 */
    if indexw(_infile_,"shy") le 0; /* continue only if data does not contains 'shy' */

    /*--------
      write the data you want, complete line read in this case
      --------*/
    put _N_= "->" _infile_;

    /*--------
      mark where the data in the file has ended
      --------*/
    if theEnd then put "-----end file ----";
  run;
  ```
- Your SAS log will look like this:

  ```
   NOTE: The infile '/folders/myshortcuts/test/file' is:
         Filename=/folders/myshortcuts/test/file,
         Owner Name=sasdemo,Group Name=sas,
         Access Permission=-rw-rw-r--,
         Last Modified=11Jan2017:22:42:56,
         File Size (bytes)=160

   -----start file ----
   _N_=1 ->The begining, :)
   _N_=3 ->line 3, all good so far.
   _N_=5 ->Finally the last line in my file!
   -----end file ----

   NOTE: 5 records were read from the infile '/folders/myshortcuts/test/file'.
         The minimum record length was 16.
         The maximum record length was 43.
   NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
         real time           0.02 seconds
         cpu time            0.03 seconds
  ```